# Как загружать большие файлы в телеграмм? Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, telethon

Есть ≈ 2.5к архивов разного размера от 20кб до 2гб. Их надо загрузить в канал телеграмм(не ссылками на другие хранилища, облака и т.д.) Подумал что это можно будет сделать через бота(Тогда я ещё не знал про ограничения в 50мб).

Написал следующий код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['send_files'])
async def send_files_handler(message: types.Message):
    files = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, file), 'rb') as f:
            try:
                # await bot.send_document(chat_id=CHAT_ID, document=f)
                await bot.send_document('CHENAL_ID', document=f)
```

Я пишу в лс боту команду `/send_files` бот начинает отправлять все файлы из указанного каталога.
Попробовал запустить, увидел после загрузки нескольких файлов ошибки. написал блок отправки в `try:` и добавил функцию записи в txt путей до файлов которые не смогли отправиться

```
try:
                await bot.send_document('CHENAL_ID', document=f)
            except:
                r_f = open(r'D:\test\erorr.txt','a')
                r_f.write(str(f)+'\n')
                f.close()
```

Написал скрипт для переноса файлов из `erorr.txt` в отдельную папку что бы потом посмотреть что с ними не так.
Понял что там по какой то причине оказались файлы до 50мб и их нет в канале. Повторил алгоритм ещё раз только в новом каталоге и с новым файлом `erorr.txt`. Снова какие то файлы загрузились, а какие то нет. И так ещё много-много раз.

Увидел [статью на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/articles/348234/) там используется "Юзер-бот", он отправляет файлы в лс боту, а он в свою очередь отправляет файл в нужный чат.

В общем нужен рабочий способ для авто загрузки файлов в канал тг до 2гб.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать локальный сервер API ботов. Как раз, что вам нужно. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server

Comment: Да, я думаю мне подойдет, но написание сервера для меня сложновато. Я думаю есть +- готовые решения(локального сервера API ботов)